# Java - how to use methods

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, imageicon

I have a list of JLabels that I am insterting into my JPanel:

```
avatarGridPanel.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("images/gui/orc_male.png", "Orc Male")));
avatarGridPanel.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("images/gui/human_male.png", "Human Male")));
avatarGridPanel.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("images/gui/tundrian_male.png", "Tundrian Male")));
avatarGridPanel.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("images/gui/brimlock_male.png", "Brimlock Male")));
```

I want to add tooltiptext to each of them.  Is there any better way than to use a temp variable to hold one of their values and then keep re-using it?

```
JLabel temp = new JLabel();
temp = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("images/gui/human_male.png", "Human Male"));
temp.setToolTipText("Human Male");
avatarGridPanel.add(temp);
```

I tried doing something like this(below) but could not get it to work.  Thanks for any help!

```
avatarGridPanel.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("images/gui/human_male.png", "Human Male")).setToolTipText("Human Male"));
```

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to keep references to them? So have `JLabel myLabel1 = new JLabel(etc,etc);` for each of them, then use these references to add the tooltips?

Comment: The error I got was:The method add(Component) in the type Container is not applicable for the arguments (void)

Comment: dann.dev: yes because I dont need to keep referenced to them. I want to keep my code neat and organized

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a function to create these for you. I do it sometimes when I have a big array and need to the same thing over and over:

```
private static JLabel makeLabel(String path, String name) {
    JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(path, name));
    label.setToolTipText(name);
    return label;
}
```

Then elsewhere in that class:

```
avatarGridPanel.add(makeLabel("images/gui/orc_male.png", "Orc Male"));
```

Comment: thanks this is what i will do then, much appreciated.  I wasn't sure if there was a better shortcut, but this will have to do.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a method where you pass in the image location, the text and the tooltip text to avoid all that code repetition.

This should work

```
private static JLabel createImageLabel(String imageLocation, String name, String toolTipText) {
    JLabel temp  = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(imageLocation, name));
    temp.setToolTipText(toolTipText);
    return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a "temp" variable, but if you do you don't want to first create an empty JLabel and then right after that a new JLabel with icon and text.

But how about creating a helper method?

```
...
avatarGridPanel.add(createLabel("images/gui/human_male.png", "Human Male"));
...

private JLabel createLabel(String iconPath, String description) {
    JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(iconPath, description));
    label.setToolTipText(description);
    return label;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to do that in one line but nothing really clean nor elegant.

Anyway, in most cases it isn't a good idea to create new instances of a class and not storing them in, at least, a local variable (even for a temporary usage).

So, the best thing to do here is to have this `temp` variable or delegate the code to something else (method/builder).